# Tomcat Manager App 404 after changing Context.xml

Tags: tomcat, centos, tomcat7, war, centos6

I have Tomcat 7.0.39 installed on CentOS 6.6 x64

I had it set up correctly so I could go to Tomcat's manager app. I then swapped /conf/context.xml to a different context.xml file (for a client's app that I was trying to get to run). After changing the context.xml file I got a 404 when navigating to the manager app.

The problem is that after changing the context.xml back to the original context.xml file I am still getting the 404 when navigating to the manager app (even though the only thing that had changed was the context.xml file and this file was now back in the original state).

I have tried the following to get the manager app working again:

- Restarted the tomcat service (multiple times)
- Restarted the entire VM
- Removed everything in /work/Catalina/
- Removed *manager* from /webapps and then added it back again when tomcat was running (Tomcat recognised it had a new webapp and then proceeded to deploy it)

The logs aren't showing any errors and catalina.out is showing that the manager app is being deployed when tomcat is starting:

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/manager
```

My question is this, what part of tomcat is storing this broken state? I would have thought that going back to the original, working context.xml would make my tomcat work again, so what could that file have changed about tomcat that is being persisted even after restarting tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

As much of important information is missing, I can also guess.

- Maybe you messed up the file permissions of the /conf/context.xml, and Tomcat can't read the file any more.
- Maybe you restored the old file incorrectly (possibly it is corrupted).
- Maybe you changed something else which was important but forgot about it
- Maybe you are calling a wrong URL. Should be like http://localhost:8080/manager/html